# Delete SMS by id

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to delete a sms in my Android application using this code:

```
val affected = contentResolver.delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/$id"), null, null)
```

But always the affected variable is 0.

P.S.: This app is set as the default SMS app and I have the permission to wirte sms.

Comment: What is $id? It seems wrong

Comment: The code is in kotlin, id is a String var, with the sms id. In java this pitch of code will be like ...Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id)...

Answer (score 0):

If it actually deletes, it should return 1 as a result.

I have just checked this code:
`contentResolver.delete(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(id).build(), null, null)`

My Uri should generally be same as yours.

**If it doesn't delete**, 0 is expected. Then make sure you're using `Telephony.Sms._ID` and not thread ID or something else.